# Replace the start and end of the string in the list of values- Python

Tags: python

I would like to remove "Timestamp(" from the start of the string and ")" at the end of the string to insert datetime values into sqlsever

How can I acheive this? Thanks

```
modified_row_values = [1, '508', '505', '613', 'CHRIST', 'LAKE ROAD', None, 'PARK', 'Orange', '156789', 'XXX-XXX-XXXX', '1', 'NNE', 'ONNE', 'LAKE ROAD', None, 'PARK', 'NY', '123456', 'SCpython@GMAIL.COM', '9CC271', '9CC271', '9CC271', '41.200263', '-74.2094', 'Karl', Timestamp('2022-12-21 17:00:00'), NaT, Timestamp('2022-12-21 17:00:00') 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', None, 'XTU', None, None, None, None, None, None, Timestamp('2022-12-21 16:24:04')]
```

(this statement works but if it finds something like (HELLO) in the list, it formats to **(HELLO**

```
#modified_row_values = [str(value).replace("timestamp(", "").rstrip(")") if value is not None else value for value in modified_row_values]
```

Below is what I have tried:

```
#modified_row_values = [str(value).replace("timestamp(", "").rstrip(")") if value is not None and str(value).startswith("timestamp(") and str(value).endswith(")") else value for value in modified_row_values]
```

Comment: that appears to be a type of object, can you just test that?

Comment: @CumminUp07, Sorry I didn't understand

Comment: it gave me as <class 'list'> for print(type(modified_row_values)); s this what you are asking?

Comment: I meant what is the type of `Timestamp()` it seems to not be a string

Answer (score 0):

define a function called format and use the following Reg Exp

```
import re

def format(s):
    match = re.match(r"Timestamp\((.*?)\)$", s)
    if match:
        s = match.group(1)
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
modified_row_values = [
  str(value).replace("Timestamp(", "").rstrip(")") if value is not None and str(value).startswith("Timestamp(") and str(value).endswith(")") else value 
  for value in modified_row_values
]
```

Comment: Isn't this same as what i have provided except the lowercase "T" right?